# SharePoint top navigation snippet public links

Tags: sharepoint-designer, navigation, snippet

My SharePoint Web Application has the following url(internal): 
    `http://mywa:85/sites/kes`

Because it's hosted in a Azure Virtual Machine, I need the following url to access it from outside(public): 
    `http://mywa.cloudapp.net:85/sites/kes`

I added a vertical navigation snippet to my custom master page and it works fine but it has the internal links and I can't access them from outside.

There is any way to edit the links in the navigation snippet?

Comment: The navigation snippet must be sourced from `Structure Navigation` or from `Managed Navigation`. You can modify those links by opening sites Navigation Settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The navigation snippet must be sourced from Structure Navigation or from Managed Navigation. You can modify those links by opening sites Navigation Settings.

1. Click on site settings
2. Select Navigation
3. Change the values